# Sorting alphabetical order always push ALL text as the first option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, string, sorting

I have been trying to sort the below array by string and it is working fine. But the catch is that, the text "ALL", should always appear at the top of the list. Since it is sorted alphabetically, the text "ALL" is moved to its natural alphabetic position.The requirement is after sorting, its should be in the first element in list. how to do this the best way ?

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <ul ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal|orderBy:'toString()'" >
        <li>{{strVal}}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>

var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.arrVal = ['All','Alabama','Alaska','American Samoa','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado','Connecticut','Delaware','District of Columbia','Federated States of Micronesia','Florida','Georgia','Guam','Hawaii','Idaho','Illinois','Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana','Maine','Marshall Islands','Maryland','Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi','Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York','North Carolina','North Dakota','Northern Mariana Islands','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon','Palau','Pennsylvania','Puerto Rico','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah','Vermont','Virgin Island','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia','Wisconsin','Wyoming']

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple, you just need to add an extra condition in the **[`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** callback to give priorities to `All` string so it shouls always be treated first.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.toUpperCase();
  var nameB = b.toUpperCase();
  if (nameA === "ALL") {
    return -1;
  } else if (nameB === "ALL") {
    return 1;
  }
//The rest of the code
```

**Demo:**

This is a Demo:

```js
var arr = ['All', 'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Federated States of Micronesia', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Island', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];


var results = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.toUpperCase();
  var nameB = b.toUpperCase();
  if (nameA === "ALL") {
    return -1;
  } else if (nameB === "ALL") {
    return 1;
  } else {
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you @chsdk. I did not want to add the conditions like ur answer inside a sort function. But i really could not find any other ideal way of doing it and i ended up using your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to update your code like this

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <ul>
        <li>All</li>
        <li ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal|orderBy:'toString()'">{{strVal}}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>

var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.arrVal = ['Alabama','Alaska','American Samoa','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado','Connecticut','Delaware','District of Columbia','Federated States of Micronesia','Florida','Georgia','Guam','Hawaii','Idaho','Illinois','Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana','Maine','Marshall Islands','Maryland','Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi','Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York','North Carolina','North Dakota','Northern Mariana Islands','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon','Palau','Pennsylvania','Puerto Rico','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah','Vermont','Virgin Island','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia','Wisconsin','Wyoming']

});
```

Comment: I was using this as my initial solution and there were conditions like not to display "All" when there is only one option in the dropdown. So i had to write some additional conditions in my template and thats why i was not able to use this solution in my current use case. But this is also another way of doing it.

Comment: Why don't you use ng-hide if you don't want to display All on some conditions?

Comment: yes, i tried that too. But apparently, we did not want to add conditions in our template. so i had to remove it.